# What are DNS TXT records and why are they needed

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, domainkeys, txt-record

I am creating a server with a primary nameserver and mutliple domains. Do i need to make TXT records for all the domain, they all have there own email, but use the mailserver from the primary.

EDIT:

I am currently on a server running CentOS and Plesk. One option i can choose is to use Domain Keys"

If i enable the domain keys, there are 2 TXT fields created, one with a long key, and one with a o=- value.

If I enable this do i still need to have the SPF records, or is this inferior to the SPF records, in terms of SPAM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TXT records were originally intended to provide an option to place **arbitrary user-comments**.

Now, they are generally used for the **[SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) anti-spam** system.

Comment: SPF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: They're also used extensively in conjunction with SRV records for DNS Service Discovery (Apple "Wide Area" Bonjour), but you don't create them yourself, you let hosts set them automatically via DNS Dynamic Update (e.g. dnsextd running alongside BIND) when they want to publish services.

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses guys, i do have another question tho. I hear you say something abouot anti-spam. I have seen this option in combination with an spam option. Now i run nameserver, so people are having there domains running with my nameserver. Should i create those TXT records for them, or are they dynamicly created as spiff commented. Thanks guys!

Comment: you must create spf record manually and depends on where your email should came from. http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html

Answer (score 6):

`TXT` records were originally intended just to store arbitrary (small) amounts of text as labels for DNS data.

However since they were the only free-form record type specified for use in DNS they were subsequently misused greatly as a dumping ground for any old crap that didn't have its own resource record type (i.e. `SPF`).

`SPF` *does* now have its own record type, but legacy systems still prefer the old `TXT` format.